# JAVA based SAML token authentication for Okta without spring

Tags: single-sign-on, saml-2.0, okta, okta-api

I have a requirement where in we have integrated our ECM software with okta. To upload documents to the ECM software, i would need to get the SAML token from okta and append the token with the document upload request webservice.

I would like to know if there are any documentations/ java code snippets which explain a simple okta-saml based authentication without any Spring security or other frameworks. 
The reason I am asking this is because, we use a webservice to uplaod the documenst to ECM software wits the SAMl token embedded.

Please let me know how to achieve a simple okta SAML authentication for the above scenario.

Thanks,
Pradeep

I have used some git hub codes without any success.

Answer (score 0):

Of course you can implement a SAMLv2 compliant Service Provider yourself, but this will take some time. I would not only consume the SAML Assertion (the XML Document) as such. The SAML message handling could be done with OpenSAML library (https://wiki.shibboleth.net/confluence/display/OS30/Home), but it won't provide you with a SAMLv2 compliant SP implementation.